# Vanilla JS Jest test click event

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Need help with a Jest test for vanilla JS method with click.
I've been searching around, but can't find anything for this. After the method, `testClick` has called, I want to test that each `selected` item was indeed clicked.

```
const selected = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
const testClick = (selectedItems) => {
    if (selectedItems.length) {
        selectedItems.forEach(item => {
            item.click();
        });
    }
}
testClick(selected);
```

main-test.js (jest test)

```
describe("Unit tests", () => {
    let container;
    let parent;
    let child1;
    let child2;
    let selectedItems;

    beforeEach(() => {
        container = window.document.body;
        parent = document.createElement("div");
        child1 = document.createElement("div");
        child2 = document.createElement("div");
        child1.classList.add("selected");
        child2.classList.add("selected");
        parent.appendChild(child1);
        parent.appendChild(child2);
        container.appendChild(parent);
        selectedItems = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
        testClick(selectedItems);
    });

    it("if 'selectedItems' & testClick() has fired, it should know that each item has been clicked", () => {
        // not sure what to do here
    });

});
```

Comment: you can also take a look at the [DOM Manipulation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-jquery) section in the jest docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve that in the setup (`beforeAll`) you can attach an eventListener to the elements with `jest.fn()` as callback and assert that the function should have been called with the expected target

```
describe("when testClick() has fired", () => {
  let clickHandler;
  beforeAll(() => {
    clickHandler = jest.fn();
    document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(div => {
      div.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
    });

    // as the `testClick()` is invoked within the application
    // you should require the implementation here instead
    // of trying to call it within the test
    require("./testClick");
  });

  it("should call the click event listerner for child1", () => {
    // not sure what to do here
    expect(clickHandler).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
        target: child1
      })
    );
  });
});
```

[working example](https://repl.it/repls/CuddlyImpeccableCoding)

Comment: Curious. If I was to use import for the “.testClick” file at the top as with Babel what would the require(“.testClick”) change to?

Comment: @user3361996 probably [something like this](https://repl.it/repls/PutridVoluminousNaturallanguage)

Comment: @user3361996 You're welcome :) I'd appreciate upvote on my comments as I'd love to get the "Just jesting" hat :P